# Could not load file or assembly 'system.core version=4.0.0.0 error in windows phone application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 application using VS Express 2012 for Windows Phone. Everything was going fine, but as soon as I have added some external APIs in my project like Google APIs for translation and ran the code, I got this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'system.core version=4.0.0.0 error in windows phone application

I have already tried some solutions like clearing my "/Phone Tools/CoreCon/10.0" and "/Phone Tools/CoreCon/11.0" and replacing System.Core.dll file.

Please help me resolve it.

This is my App.xaml file where I'm getting this error:

```
<Application

x:Class="WOI.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WOI">

</Application>
```

Comment: maybe the APIs you are using, do not support the Windows Phone version you are building the app for?

Comment: windows phone 8 and it is Google's official translation API for windows phones applications